# Joomla - Missing page

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, k2

We have inherited a Joomla site - which has been built using the K2 plugin. All seems straightforward enough - but we have one particular page which is active and cannot be found anywhere in the CMS - we have searched all items - every other page appears apart from this one - can anyone advise on a way we could track the page down?

Any help would be gratefully appreciated!

Comment: This is really not a programming question, but is the page linked from somewhere? The non SEF url should help you find it. You could temporarily turn off sef urls and follow the link.   Also you don't say what version of Joomla this is. If it is an old version it could be the old static page type.

Answer (score 0):

can you send your path url and What are you looking for?

maybe, it is a module that only appear on certain pages.